# Python Odd Number counting program continues to give me an error

Tags: python, numbers, return

I am trying to make a program that asks the user to input numbers, using a while loop and then eventually return how many are odd.

Here is my code (I am terrible at formatting so feel free to edit!):

```
count = 0

num = int(input("Enter your number: "))
print ("Here is your number: " + str(num))

while num != -1:

    if num % 2 == 1:
        count +=1
    input num = int(input("Enter your number: "))

    print(num)

print(count)
```

NOTE : -1 should not be counted as a value! (this was an instruction included)

Comment: so what is the problem and the error?

Comment: Your while loop should be used to count the number of entries so it eventually gives the count. Currently, the user would have to enter -1 to get the count.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Your initial question used `print` without parentheses (Python 2), but a subsequent edit added parentheses (Python 3).

Answer (score 3):

A simple rule to figure out how many odd numbers are between zero and a given number is to first check if its an odd number and if it is, then divide it by two and round it UP and that is your odd numbers count. If it is even, simply divide it by two and that is your odd number count.
Even example: given number 12. Dividing it by 2 is 6. (1,3,5,7,9,11)
Odd example: given number 15. Dividing it by 2 is 7.5 rounding it up is 8 (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
**Updated to match OP requirements** 
 
The code when it is launched will ask the user to input a list  of numbers separated by commas and will return for each number in the list if it is even or odd, also a running count of odd numbers will be shown.

Python code:

```
def odd_counter(int_input):
    counter = 0
    for n in int_input:
        if n % 2 == 1:
            counter += 1
            print("{} number is ODD. Total count of odd numbers is: {}".format(n,counter))
        else:
            print("{} number is EVEN. Total count of odd number is: {}".format(n,counter))

numb_list = input("Please enter numbers seperated by comma: ")

numb_list = [int(numb) for numb in numb_list.split(',')]

odd_counter(numb_list)
```

Comment: This is a clever concept, but I think the OP wanted a user to input multiple non-consecutive numbers and count how many of them are odd.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the code. Now when it is launched it will ask for input of numbers separated by commas and will output if a number out of a list is even or odd and return a running count of odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
count = 0
num = 0
while num != -1:
    inp = input("Enter your number: ")
    num = int(inp)
    print ("Here is your number: " + inp)
    if num % 2 == 1:
        count += 1

print (count)
```

This will keep asking the user for a number until they enter -1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the `while` loop ends at some point. In your example, the user would have to enter `-1` to get out of it and see `count` printed.

Try this code below (it is Python 2 because your initial code appeared to be this version).

```
count = 0
entries = 0
max_entries = 5 # Or however many you want

while entries < max_entries:
    # Check number is odd and not -1 (could also check number is >0 if need to exclude all negative numbers)
    num = int(input("Enter your number: "))
    print "Here is your number: " + str(num)
    entries += 1
    if num % 2 == 1 and num != -1:
        count += 1

print str(count) + " numbers are odd"
```

I should add that you haven’t mentioned what problem you’re having, so I’m assuming it’s that the loop never ended. Also, on line 10, `input num =` is a syntax error. The `input` at the start is unnecessary.

Comment: @JackSmith The answer above will work. Your line 10 error must be because you have put `input` before `num` which is not needed and does not make sense. Also, you can run all of the input cycles in the `while` loop without running one before the loop.